# SQL Server backup restore issues?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Ok, so I'm having a bit of an issue - I executed some code on my SQL Server and didn't realize that I didn't have the WHERE bit selected. Of course, when I saw the `"608 rows affected"` rather than `"1 row affected"`, I freaked a bit.

Luckily, I have a backup saved, but for some reason, I'm getting a couple issues. Now, I took the server down, so I know that it's not being used by anyone, but it's giving me the following error

> "Restore failed for Server 'myserver'.
>
> System.Data.sqlclient.sqlerror: Exclusive access could not be obtained
>   because the database is in use. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)"

I saw something that stated I should be using

```
Alter Database Databases
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

RESTORE DATABASE PRODUCT
FROM DISK = ''
```

but I'm having three reservations about this code. First, I'm completely unsure of how to turn multi_user back on. Second, I don't know where the program stores its backups. Third, this SQL is a bit above my head - I'm relatively new to the language, honestly, so I'm not sure how this will affect things.

Anyone have any answers to my troubles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the database to single user is correct.  When you are complete with your restoration you'll execute this

```
alter database YourDb
set multi_user
```

As for where your .bak file resides, you'll have to find it prior to restoring.

Answer (score 8):

I might suggest instead of overwriting the existing database from the backup, that you instead recover the backup with a different database name... this way you can have the current and previous databases side-by-side.

Then, you can simply write an update statement to recover the data from just that one specific table instead of resetting the whole database.

EDIT: The specifics would depend on your environment, but the restore would look something like this:

```
restore database PRODUCT_OLD
from disk='C:\PRODUCT.bak'
with
    move 'PRODUCT_Data' to 'C:\PRODUCT_OLD_Data.MDF',
    move 'PRODUCT_Log' to 'C:\PRODUCT_OLD_Log.LDF'
```

And then the update statement would also be based on your specific table...

Comment: Any examples on how you might do that?

Comment: +1, this is a much better approach - don't compound your problems by deleting the only good data you have left.

Comment: While this was a better answer, I ended up restoring the whole database because there were another couple errors that I needed to fix as well, and the backup caught all of them. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 6):

right on the database click tasks->**takeoffline**  , when its succeed do the same thing but put it **Bring Online**
then try to restore your database

Comment: These seems to have helped me. Thanks for the idea.  Although, it seemed to take a long time to go offline.

Answer (score 3):

Scary.

Ok, some things to check:

1. Make sure you are the only person connected to the server.
2. Make sure no other applications, web servers, app servers, etc. hold connections to your DB.
3. Make sure your SQL manager has no open windows to tables or other objects in your database.

THEN you should be able to do the restore w/o single user stuff.

Comment: I actually shut down the server itself so that no one could connect to it but myself, and the only program that should be connecting to it would be the server management studio program, so I think I'm good there.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the activity Monitor and see if users are still logged in then kill the process for that user using the respective db.
Then go ahead restore the backup